# htaccess cookie / URL param results in infinite loop, how can I avoid this?

Tags: htaccess

I have a cookie on my site and would like to have this cookie in the URL (always*), something like this:

`www.domain.com/?lang=en` OR `www.domain.com/subscribe/?lang=en`

*(I'm not sure if I would like it ALWAYS, maybe I can exclude some directories? I guess I can do this by adding an extra `RewriteCond`.)

But the main problem is my code now results in a loop, below is the code I use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Now my URL results in:

`www.domain.com/?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en` ...  etc.

How can I simply add cookie information to the URL only once, and not loop all the time?

Answer (score 4):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [R,QSA,L]
```

That way you will not not get infinite loop because of 1st negative condition.

Comment: thx! yes that solved the looping! Great

Only i run Drupal and my other urls are now different:
www.domain.com/subscribe
is now
www.domain.com/index.php?currency=en&q=subscribe

i guess because of the last rule:
/$1?lang=%1 [R,QSA,L]

i will try to find out how to make a better rule now

Comment: Glad to know. If you think this answer helped you in anyway pls mark it as accepted so that others can also benefit from this.